# Loading angularjs files in plnkr

Tags: angular

This sample code creates a angular component.  I am confused as to how it is loading main.js and story.component.js files into index.html ?

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview
```

There is no direct inclusion of these files in index.html

Below is the entire code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular polyfill required everywhere -->
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/router.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/http.dev.js"></script>

  <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {
          'api': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}, 
          'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'} 
        } 
      });
    System.import('app/main')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <my-story>Loading Demo ...</my-story>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading is handled by SystemJS:

```
System.import('app/main')
```

imports the `main.js` as described in `config.js`:

```
System.config.packages.app.main = './main.ts'
```

which basically tells loader that module `main` is part of the `app` package and can be found in file `main.ts` in the same directory.

The rest of the files are loaded with import statements.